# How to configure alignment and indentation of terraform code inside VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terraform

I use VS Code to develop terraform code. My current plugin for terraform is:

```
Name: Terraform
Id: hashicorp.terraform
Description: Syntax highlighting, linting, formatting, and validation for Hashicorp's Terraform
Version: 1.4.0
Publisher: HashiCorp
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HashiCorp.terraform
```

Consider the following code:

```
output "sql_server" {
  description = "A dictionary of objects containing various Azure Sql Server properties per respective location."
  value = {
    for k, instance in azurerm_sql_server.instance : k =>
    {
      resource_group_name = instance.resource_group_name
      fully_qualified_domain_name = instance.fully_qualified_domain_name 
      name = instance.name
      location = instance.location
      is_primary = instance.location == var.primary_location
      admin_login = instance.administrator_login
    }
  }
}
```

I would like it to be reformatted like this when saving the file:

```
output "sql_server" {
    description = "A dictionary of objects containing various Azure Sql Server properties per respective location."
    value = {
        for k, instance in azurerm_sql_server.instance : k =>
        {
            resource_group_name         = instance.resource_group_name
            fully_qualified_domain_name = instance.fully_qualified_domain_name 
            name                        = instance.name
            location                    = instance.location
            is_primary                  = instance.location == var.primary_location
            admin_login                 = instance.administrator_login
        }
    }
}
```

Two things happen here:

- Indentation of 4 spaces was applied
- All the assignments within the same block were aligned

There is a lot of information on the web on how to do it, but I am must be especially stupid for being unable to make it work, so I would like to get a very concrete answer containing the following details:

- What terraform plugin to use
- What exactly to write in my settings.json

My current user settings.json file is:

```
{
    "workbench.startupEditor": "welcomePage",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "terminal.integrated.scrollback": 1000,
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": -1,
    "diffEditor.renderSideBySide": false,
    "extensions.ignoreRecommendations": false,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "PowerShell ISE",
    "powershell.codeFormatting.whitespaceBeforeOpenBrace": false,
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "terminal.integrated.rendererType": "dom",
    "terraform.path": "C:\\Users\\mkharitonov\\.terraform\\terraform.exe"
}
```

My local workspace settings.json file is:

```
{
    "git.ignoreLimitWarning": true,
    "powershell.codeFormatting.openBraceOnSameLine": false,
    "powershell.codeFormatting.whitespaceBeforeOpenBrace": false,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

Comment: The autoformatter on that plugin (ctrl+shift+i) will run the `terraform fmt` command. This is the opinionated, zero option autoformatter that leads to a canonical style. I wouldn't diverge from that even though it uses 2 spaces for indentation. There's a benefit to opinionated auto formatters that means good Terraform code always looks the same.

Comment: What about alignment of assignments?

Comment: Yes it will do that. I recommend running the formatter on the code so you can see the changes it makes.

Comment: Hmm, I can give up on 4 characters. If that is the case, then I am all set, right?

Comment: The plugin formatter does not work, I guess this is why I posted this question. I remember I was using the plugin, but had no formatting. I will post a bug in the plugin github repo.

Comment: Github issue - https://github.com/hashicorp/vscode-terraform/issues/393

Answer (score 12):

Easy, install both the [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) and the extension made by [HashiCorp Terraform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HashiCorp.terraform).

If you need to you can go into your vscode settings.json and add a section for terraform.

```
"[terraform]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "hashicorp.terraform",
    "editor.tabSize": 2, // optionally
  },
  "[terraform-vars]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 2 // optionally
  },
```

Comment: I'm assuming this only works w/ `hashicorp.terraform` as the formtter if you have the CLI installed as well? re: when looking at the HashiCorp Terraform output, an error is raise: `Error for "textDocument/formatting" (ID 27): [-32098] Terraform (CLI) is required. Please install Terraform or make it available in $PATH` (Windows OS)

Comment: @Metro Smurf is correct. Format Document only worked when I installed Terraform with scoop

Answer (score 5):

It is recommended to use 2 spaces for terraform code instead of tabs or 4 spaces.
You might see it in the [Style Conventions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/syntax/style.html)

To configure the VS Code:

1. the terraform should be installed on your Mac
2. edit the `settings.json` and add the following:

```json
"[terraform]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

After this all your `*.tf` files will be automatically formatted on save.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are fine and work.  However, it is really annoying to have a 4 character indent and have the auto-save process snap it back to 2 characters.

For whatever reason, VSCODE and the Terraform plugin default to 4 spaces.  This can be changed by adding these blocks to your `settings.json`:

```
    "[terraform]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 2
    },
    "[terraform-vars]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 2
    },
```

These will keep your indents to the recommended 2 spaces when you are editing and avoid the violent snap from 4 to 2 spaces when the auto-save process saves your file.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the formatting function of `terraform fmt`, it just format all tf files in your directory and aligns their format. It is easier to implement and more standardized in formatting terraform. For more, here is the [official doc](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/fmt).

Answer (score 2):

**Solution for macOS + VSCode**

If you have problems with auto-formatting you may try doing so:

- Install HashiCorp Terraform plugin
- Install Terraform version manager:

  ```
  brew install tfenv
  ```
- Ask `tfenv` to use the specific version used by your project, for instance:

  ```
  tfenv use 0.12.20
  ```
- Add the following in your `settings.json`:

  ```
  "[terraform]": {
      "editor.formatOnSave": true
  }
  ```

Comment: not working still saying install formatter

Answer (score 0):

If any of the above suggestions are unsuccessful, just install [Terraform Format on Save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=matheusq94.TFS) extension.

Answer (score 0):

The guys from Hashicorp wanted to solve all formating issue and so they introduced the command `terraform fmt` that provides a standard formatting for all terraform code.

```
 terraform fmt [options] [target...]
```

You can pick from their list of options to serve different purposes, but the most useful one is:

```
terraform fmt -recursive
```

Running this from the root will ensure all files from all subdirectories are checked and formatted.

Read the full documentation: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/fmt

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the path pointing to the Terraform binary installed, so ended up with this in the settings to make it work:

```json
  "terraform.languageServer.terraform.path": "/opt/homebrew/bin/terraform",
  "[terraform]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "hashicorp.terraform",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "file"
  },
  "[terraform-vars]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "hashicorp.terraform",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "file"
  },
```